# Recaptcha отложенная загрузка инициализации скрипта

Tags: javascript, оптимизация-сайтов, recaptcha

В процессе оптимизации скорости загрузки сайта столкнулся с необходимостью убрать стандартную инициализацию Google recaptcha v3. И сделать инициализацию по требованию, динамическую. Сейчас оно выглядит так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И после загрузки страницы добавляется в блок
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это правильно сделать ? Попробовал метод предложенный [тут](https://overcoder.net/q/1338150/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-recaptcha-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8) Но к сожалению чего-то не сработало. Добавление кода через async не скрывает инициализацию. Google Page Speed всё ещё показывает проблему с лишним кодом.

Так же пробовал метод предложенный [тут](https://otshelnik-fm.ru/post-group/dinamicheskaya-zagruzka-google-recaptcha-gruzim-vse-eyo-resursy-po-trebovaniyu/?action-rcl=login) *для WordPress но тоже что-то пошло не так

```js
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'fwpl_dinamic_recaptcha', 100 );
function fwpl_dinamic_recaptcha() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() )
        return;

    echo "<script>
    var key = 'some-sitekey';
    function loadScript() {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=kwplOnload&render=explicit';
        script.async = true;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    jQuery(function($){
        $('body').on('click', '.rcl-login,.rcl-register', function(){
            loadScript();
        });
    });
    if(rcl_url_params['action-rcl']){
        loadScript();
    }
    var kwplOnload = function() {
        grecaptcha.render('kwpl_google_id',{'sitekey': key});
    }
 </script>
";
}
```

Comment: Рекапча ставиться на обычную html страницу, в качестве потравщика писем используется утилита swiftmailer.

Comment: Что именно пошло не так с последним вариантом? У вас не Wordpress?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/513868/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Должно как-то так работать, только с правильным ключом и на правильном домене. Пиши что не получается, помогу

```js
var key = 'site-key';
function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js';
    script.async = true;
    script.onload = function () {
      grecaptcha.ready(function () {
        grecaptcha.render('captcha_id',{'sitekey': key});
      }) 
    }
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
document.getElementById('button_id').onclick = loadScript
```

```html
<button id="button_id">Капча!</button>
<div id="captcha_id"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо, сработало. Пришлось немного доработать что б только на первый клик инициализировало, а не каждый раз.